# How to use UserMetadata and other types in firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

How does one import types from firebase? I am calling the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function in auth and I want to save the result in a type defined variable. From looking at the code and docs, I see it should be the UserCredential type here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential

It is unclear to me how I can import and use this type.

Thanks!

Comment: Users in Firebase don't have a type as far as I know. Can you provide more information (or a link) of the "type" you're referring to?

Comment: I am referring to the type returned after calling `signInWithEmailAndPassword` here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword. The function signature says it returns a promise of a UserCredential type defined here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That UserCredential class is used for delivering information to you from various API calls.  There is no reason to create it yourself.

The operationType property is not a user type.  The docs you linked say:

> operationType could be 'signIn' for a sign-in operation, 'link' for a linking operation and 'reauthenticate' for a reauthentication operation.

That's just telling you what happened inside the auth SDK that resulted in the User object you received through the UserCredential object.

Users don't have an assigned "type" in Firebase Auth - that's up to you to assign and record in your own app, usually in a database.

Comment: Thanks! This is the conclusion I ended up arriving at. I just wanted to save the user information in the browser/javascript state to know if I needed to show a login screen or if I could allow them into the app. I thought I could use the firebase types to do this but in the end I made my own type and took the info I wanted out of the UserCredential object returned after calling `signInWithEmailAndPassword`